# Through and by (sentences)

Tags: prepositions

The expression "to talk by the phone" is correct and I'm pretty sure if you use "through" instead of "by" it makes sense as well, but what about this expression:
•You never know what's gonna come THROUGH that door•

Could I use "by" in the expression (or sentence) from above? I know the word "by" has a lot of meanings but in this case, to me, it means "by the means of" so is this correct? I know it may not be that common but could it still be considered  as correct?

It's like saying:
Travel by car or Travel through car, to me both of these are ok but the first one is more common

Comment: I talk **on** the phone, not **by** and not **through**. I never travel **through** a car - at least I try not to, as that could be very painful, if not fatal. And finally, the phrase **come by** has a very specific meaning (or meanings) - see: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+by

Comment: You've misunderstood the way these prepositions are used: "to talk by the phone" isn't correct, as *by* in that context would be understood as *next to*, and using *through* would make no sense at all.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). JP, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: +1 I've read and heard *talk through the phone* on many occasions. While it's not common, I think it's a mistake to say that it's wrong. (It's implied—or it used to be—that you mean you are talking *through* a phone line to the person at the other end.) Also, you could say that you *talk by phone* (no article) rather than, perhaps, *talk by megaphone* or *talk by speech synthesis*. It would be unusual—but not incorrect. An analysis of this is a lot more complex that any of the comments here (including my own)—and it certainly *doesn't* deserve to be punted to ELL since it's far from "trivial."

Comment: And just to clarify. I agree with the background of your question. Is your question actually if it's okay to say, *You never know what's gonna come BY that door*? As in, somebody *travelled by door*? If so, you should clarify that in the question itself. I can see no reason why it would be completely unacceptable. But even if technically along the same lines as the rest of your analysis, nobody would ever actually use such an expression. Unless they were magic doors.

Comment: When I said "come by that door" I was using the word "by" with the meaning of "by means of" and just wanted to know if it was correct even if it's not usual